# Rare/Epic Gear World of Warcraft

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What is the best raid/instance for a level 75 Paladin to be joining in order to get optimum PvE gear for dps/leveling with.

Comment: You should make your question title reflect the specificity of the question you are asking.

Comment: Don't even think about raids before level 80

Comment: More specifically, don't even think about epic gear before level 80.

Comment: I feel like these comments reflect the unreasonable mindset that has taken over WoW - namely, that no content is worth doing before level cap, and you should grind quests to get there ASAP. There is plenty of fun to be had if you can get a group together for the older raids, and some people may prefer to visit some of them while leveling up, rather than killing another hundred arctic rats.

Comment: @sjohnston. You make a good point. People focus alot on just getting to 80, (and soon 85..lol).You can actually level faster if you do the raids within your current level range. There are also numerous quests to get you into those instances for gear/XP/gold rewards. I found i missed alot of stuff (including gear) grinding my way to 80 as fast as possible. There is also alot of good gear can only be acquired by reputation, so worthwhile to pay attention to that while levelling. Blizzard have anticipated this sort of beahviour and reward those who play for reputation rather than XP.

Comment: @sjohnston - The question specifically asked for optimum PvE gear for leveling or dps at level 75, which excludes preWotLK raids.  There's nothing wrong with doing content for content's sake, but the bulk fo the gear he gets there is outclassed by questable or Wrath regular instance blues.

Comment: +1 sjohnston - I remember, when I was a lad, the top level was a mere 60 - there was plenty of raids to be had between 40-60!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahn'kahet / Gundrak / Drak Tharon Keep has dropped good gear for me as for my Tank/healer specs. You can try Halls of Lightning in Storm Peaks but best go with very well geared party into Ulduar. So, Storm Peaks is perhaps the best. Nax is the entry level raid instance for new 80's. You could also try and get into a [Sartharion](http://www.wowwiki.com/Sartharion) raid which you can get to via Theramore on Kalimdor. I didn't really do Naxxramas and skipped it. Went back later for the achievements. Lots of fun in a 25 man raid though.

Basically a good raid party that is well geared can help pull you through the instances.

But looking for the rare gear, you can consider trying to get the [Tier 9 gear](http://www.wowwiki.com/Tier_9). [This](http://www.wowwiki.com/Armor_set) guide is not bad either. A lot of good gear can be acquired via badges. Ultimately you are preparing for level 80 raiding in 10 man dungeons. [This](http://wowgrrl.com/2009/04/30/level-80-protection-paladin-pre-raid-gear-list/#ixzz0IZdtoCEk&C) guide is a good for an idea about which instances to use for raiding, (it is geared for pallies, but it's good for any class preparing for raids.).

Comment: You'd have to be level 80 for anyone to take you to a Sartharion or Naxxramas raid. Not sure if you can even enter the instances below that. Tier 9 gear and heroics also require level 80.

Comment: @Carl. Correct. I hadn't done Nax for so long I had forgot that it's a level 80 minimum...

Answer (score 3):

At level 75, you should also have available a set constructed by a Blacksmith which should be fine to level with.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Kaliban's Loot Lists](http://www.wow-loot.com/)